Extra space between LineMark point and y-axis line in SwiftUi Charts
I'm using Swift Charts in a SwiftUI app to create a line chart. However, with my current data, I'm experiencing extra space between the Y-axis and the first LineMark point. I would like the LineMark to start directly from the Y-axis. I would also like the same adjustment at the end.
struct ChartView: View {
    let data = [ChartData(day: "Monday", value: 2),
                ChartData(day: "Tuesday", value: 2.5),
                ChartData(day: "Wednesday", value: 2.45),
                ChartData(day: "Thursday", value: 1.76),
                ChartData(day: "Friday", value: 2),
                ChartData(day: "Saturday", value: 15.3),
                ChartData(day: "Sunday", value: 2.4)]
    
    let linearGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.accentColor.opacity(0.4),
                                                                    Color.accentColor.opacity(0.2)]),
                                        startPoint: .top,
                                        endPoint: .bottom)
    var selectedMaeker: Double = 2.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(data) { value in
                AreaMark(x: .value("Days", value.day),
                         y: .value("Values", value.value))
                .alignsMarkStylesWithPlotArea()
                .interpolationMethod(.linear)
                .foregroundStyle(linearGradient)
                
                LineMark(x: .value("Year", value.day),
                         y: .value("Population", value.value))
                .interpolationMethod(.linear)
                
                PointMark(x: .value("Year", value.day),
                          y: .value("Population", value.value))
                .interpolationMethod(.linear)
                .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .bottomTrailing, spacing: 10) {
                    if selectedMaeker == value.value {
                        Text("T")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .interpolationMethod(.linear)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }
        .chartXAxisLabel(position: .bottom, alignment: .center) {
            Text("x title")
        }
        .chartYAxisLabel(position: .leading, alignment: .center) {
        }
        
        .padding(10)
    }
}



Does this answer your question? SwiftUI Chart expanded
